# BURAI eliminates atoms when I try to modify the input file

Tags: density-functional-theory, quantum-espresso, ab-initio-calculations

I'd like to get the monolayer input file for MoS2 using BURAI 1.3. I downloaded the .cif file from Materials Project and with the Modeler function I created a Monolayer MoS2 but when I clicked "Reflect on the input file" my table of atoms' coordinate was empty. I followed this [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dNYTLL8PF_4). How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Did you go to the hidden folder in your home directory? I download the CIF from Materials Project and started working in the initial directory but the output from BURAI is saved in *.burai* folder in my home directory.

Comment: In my output (I have a folder with the input file from BURAI) there's no atom. I think that the problem is when I click "Reflect on My input file", because after that I have no coordinates anymore

Comment: Don't click at the text in the right-top menu. Just go clicking in the arrow at the left bottom side of the BURAI windows and then in the three horizontal lines, go for *Save as...*.

Comment: I think that's what I'm doing. I modify with the Modeler, get my Monolayer. I Press the arrow the First Time and I click yes when It says "Finish to model the slab?". Then I click again the arrow at the left bottom side and now I get the "Reflect this model Upon the input file?" . If I click yes BURAI erases all of my Atomic coordinates :(

Comment: Well, I followed those instructions and got the new input files in a new d(hidden) directory without any issues.

Comment: Are you using Linux or Windows?

Comment: Please turn your URL into a hyperlink.

Comment: @CoolerThanACooler, Linux: Ubuntu